Scope or restrict package in child module in Android

Scoped parent classes in child modules. Feature A and Feature B are using core as their parent module.

All Api Calling is done in Core . Is it possible to scoped or restrict classes or packages in child Modules
Android Project
  + project-core/     <- Model classes share across modules
  | + src/main/java/
  |   + Feature_A_Model_Classs
  |.  + Feature_B_Model_Classs
  + Feature-A/      <- this require Feature_A_Model_Classs
  | + dependency: project-core
  |
  + Feature-B/     <- this require Feature_A_Model_Classs
  | + dependency: project-core

Can I scoped Feature_A_Model_Classs to Feature-A and Feature_B_Model_Classs to Feature-B
I mean I want to implement a way via which Feature-A shouldn't have access to Feature_B_Model_Classs and vise versa
Or is there any way in Dagger Hilt to scoped this ?
